# Simple jQuery getJSON Call to Twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I have read many Twitter & jQuery questions on here but none seem to answer my question. I am simply trying to grab 5 "tweets" from a public user. I am not doing anything with the data at this step, but my callback function never fires.

```
    $.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=?",
    {
        screen_name: 'dojo',
        count: '5'
    },

    function (data) {
        alert("IT WORKED!");
    });
```

[Here is the same code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sCneb/)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you check the error console? There are errors in your fiddle

Comment: I didn't. Can you tell I'm new? But the error was: 400 Bad Request

Comment: This could be a conflict between browser policy and cross site scripting. You may need to make use of something like xhr.js to work around those policies. Also on that same note, why not use some server side scripting to fetch the data, then pass it up to the javascript via ajax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't going to work because Twitter has now required that you authenticate in order to fetch tweets for a given user.

Reference: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline Look at 'Authentication' info.

You'll want to use a [library](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) to help get an oauth signature and make the request.

Comment: Even for public users?

User timelines belonging to protected users may only be requested when the authenticated user either "owns" the timeline or is an approved follower of the owner.

Comment: I believe so. Look at the deprecation notice. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/public_timeline. They're referring you to 'sample', which unfortunately returns a random sample of public statuses: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/sample

Comment: You must be right. I changed the API from 1.1 to 1 and it worked as expected. Thank you.

Comment: He is right.. follow this address http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=?&screen_name=BreakingNews&count=5 and you get  `({"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]});`